# Pass Ipython / Jupyter variables to Powershell commands

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

When on Linux (bash) to list the contents of a directory in Jupyter I can simply do:

```py
path = './foo/bar'
%ls {path}
```

I could not find a way achieve the same when running Jupyter on Windows (powershell). Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too hasty in asking this! One should just replace the backslashes with fwdshlashes and add an additional one at the beginning like so:

```py
path = ".\\foo\bar\"
%ls {path}
```